# Где можно изучить Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем добрый день. Решил изучить Redux. Подскажите русскоязычные материалы. Например видио-уроки или статьи. Сам смысл и суть его использования понимаю , а как писать его код не очень понимаю. Использовать его буду в React.

Comment: Гугл что-то говорит по этому поводу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй:
[Redux-in-russian](https://rajdee.gitbooks.io/redux-in-russian/content/docs/introduction/)

или

[На Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/279249/)

Comment: Redux in russian там заголовок Базовые концепции не переведён на русский язык.